# Custom column holds multiple values

Tags: sql-server

This is my code for a query to produce a specific report. This works, however when I added the last select statement

```
(Select Name 
 from RPT_CUSTOM_LIST_VALUES 
 where CUSTOM_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID = RI1.CUST_10) AS [Application]
```

The `RI1.Cust_10` column holds multiple values delimited by commas. How can I get it so that the look up table pulls each value and provides the correct name for that value? I cannot create or modify the tables within this database.

```
select 
    RI1.incident_id as [Project Incident #],
    (Select Name from RPT_CUSTOM_LIST_VALUES 
     where CUSTOM_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID = RI1.CUST_02) as [Business Name],
    RI1.NAME as [Project Name],
    RI1.INCIDENT_STATUS_NAME as [Phase],
    (Select Name from RPT_CUSTOM_LIST_VALUES 
     where CUSTOM_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID = RI1.CUST_09) as [Key Milestone Name],
    convert(nvarchar(10), RI1.CUST_26,103) as [Key Milestone Date],  -- leave as date
    convert(nvarchar(10), RI1.CUST_29,103) as [Target Completion Date], -- leave as date
    RI1.SEVERITY_NAME as [Status Color],
    RI1.CUST_01 as [Status Summary],
    RI1.OWNER_NAME as [IT Owner],
    (Select Name from RPT_CUSTOM_LIST_VALUES 
     where CUSTOM_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID = RI1.CUST_10) AS [Application]
from 
    RPT_INCIDENTS RI1   
where 
    RI1.PROJECT_ID = 445
    and RI1.IS_DELETED = 0
    and (RI1.INCIDENT_STATUS_NAME <> '5.1-Cancelled' and RI1.INCIDENT_STATUS_NAME <> '5.2-Completed')
```

My output should be, however, the last column should have names not values.  The values are from the Lookup table and I need a way to pull that data so that the values are now names.

[Report Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC4MB.png)

Comment: At first, it is very bad idea to put sub-queries into SELECT clause. At second, it looks like you have DB design issue. At third, please describe the desired output.
The easiest and most stupid way to fix your problem is to put "TOP 1" into your sub-queries.

Comment: I added the output.  The DB design is from a canned program and I can do nothing about that.  Reading the TOP 1, that's not going to help me.  If I don't have the select sub-queries, my data doesn't pull correctly.   It's the Application Field that is my issue.

Comment: You should **never ever** store multiple values into a single column - this is in violation of even the **first normal form** of relational database design - and it will cause you grief and headache all the time. Just **don't do it**.....

Comment: Marc, I agree.  It's a canned program so I can't make any changes to it.  Which is causing me grief.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test without your data, but hopefully it will work for you:

```
select RI1.incident_id as [Project Incident #]
    , [Business Name] = s1.Name
    ,RI1.NAME as [Project Name] 
    ,RI1.INCIDENT_STATUS_NAME as [Phase]
    , [Key Milestone Name] = s2.Name
    ,convert(nvarchar(10), RI1.CUST_26,103) as [Key Milestone Date]  -- leave as date
    ,convert(nvarchar(10), RI1.CUST_29,103) as [Target Completion Date] -- leave as date
    ,RI1.SEVERITY_NAME as [Status Color]
    ,RI1.CUST_01 as [Status Summary]
    ,RI1.OWNER_NAME as [IT Owner]
    , [Application] = LEFT(s3.App,LEN(APP) - SIGN(LEN(s3.APP)))
From RPT_INCIDENTS AS RI1  
OUTER APPLY (Select TOP 1 i.Name from RPT_CUSTOM_LIST_VALUES as i where i.CUSTOM_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID = RI1.CUST_02) as s1
OUTER APPLY (Select TOP 1 i.Name from RPT_CUSTOM_LIST_VALUES as i where i.CUSTOM_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID = RI1.CUST_09) as s2
OUTER APPLY (SELECT App = (
    Select i.Name + ','
    from RPT_CUSTOM_LIST_VALUES as i 
    where i.CUSTOM_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID = RI1.CUST_10
    FOR XML PATH(''))
) as s3
where RI1.PROJECT_ID = 445
    and RI1.IS_DELETED = 0
    and (RI1.INCIDENT_STATUS_NAME <> '5.1-Cancelled' and RI1.INCIDENT_STATUS_NAME <> '5.2-Completed')
```

Comment: Thanks, I still get this error message. Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '32685,32686,32689' to data type int.

Comment: I added the convert to the statement, it worked, however, the Application field can have one or many enteries,  this is only pulling the first one.  I need all of them.  Sorry to be a pain.
OUTER APPLY (SELECT App = (
    Select i.Name + ','
    from RPT_CUSTOM_LIST_VALUES as i 
    where convert(varchar(5),i.CUSTOM_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID) = RI1.CUST_10
    FOR XML PATH(''))
) as s3

Comment: I do not see the data. It should return the list. Please test that sub-query alone with test "CUST_10" value

Comment: It didn't work either.  If there is a single data entry in the field, it will not pick it up.  And it doesn't pick up the first data entry if there are multiple entries in some of the records.  I'm at a loss.

Comment: Sorry, can't help. If you provide insert statements with sample data, somebody could help.